# Another proof for complex solutions and solutions in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, alternative-proof, polynomial-rings

> Let $S = \{f_1 , ... , f_r\} \subset \mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$
>
> Prove that there exists $x \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\forall i, f_i(x) = 0 \iff $ for infinitely many $p$, $\exists x_p \in F_p$ such that   $\forall i, f_i(x_p) = 0$ where $F_p$ is some field of characteristic $p$.

I have been stuck on this question for a while now. I was looking for a proof and I found a SE post here

[Relationship between a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ to a finite set of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ and solutions in finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468962)

but I wanted to know if there was a purely algebraic way to prove this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purely algebraic way to prove this is by using Nullstellensatz.

If $f_1, \dotsc, f_r$ don't have a common zero in $\mathbb C$, then by Nullstellensatz, the ideal generated by these polynomials over $\mathbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ contains the constant polynomial $1$. Hence there exist polynomials $g_1, \dotsc, g_r \in \mathbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ such that $f_1g_1 + \dotsc + f_rg_r = 1$ as an identity of polynomials.

Now you should convince yourself that, by replacing the coefficients of the $g_i$'s with indeterminates, the identity $f_1g_1 + \dotsc + f_rg_r = 1$ becomes a system of linear equations in these indeterminates, with integral coefficients.

The existence of $g_1, \dotsc, g_r$ then means that this system of linear equations has a solution in $\mathbb C$. But since all the coefficients are in $\mathbb Z$, hence in $\mathbb Q$, we know that there must already be a solution in $\mathbb Q$.

Therefore, there exist polynomials $g_1, \dotsc, g_r\in \mathbb Q[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, such that $f_1g_1 + \dotsc + f_rg_r = 1$. Clearing the denominators, we get polynomials $h_1, \dotsc, h_r\in\mathbb Z[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, such that $f_1h_1 + \dotsc + f_rh_r = d$ for some non-zero integer $d$. Hence for any $p$ coprime to $d$, the polynomials $f_1, \dotsc, f_r$ cannot have a common zero in any field of characteristic $p$.

---

The other direction is similar. Assume that $f_1, \dotsc, f_r$ have a common zero in $\mathbb C$.

Let $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$. By Nullstellensatz, they already have a common zero $(y_1, \dotsc, y_n)$ in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ (otherwise the ideal they generate in $\overline{\mathbb Q}[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ would contain the constant polynomial $1$, hence no common zero in $\mathbb C$).

Let $E$ be the number field generated by the algebraic numbers $y_1, \dotsc, y_n$ and let $\mathcal{O}_E$ be the ring of integers of $E$. Choose a non-zero integer $d$ such that each $dy_i$ are algebraic integers.

Now for any prime number $p \nmid d$, choose a prime ideal $\mathcal P$ of $\mathcal{O}_E$ above $p$, so that the quotient $F_p = \mathcal{O}_E/\mathcal P$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$.

It is then clear that, if we put $z_i = d^{-1}((dy_i)\mod {\mathcal P}) \in F_p$, then $(z_1, \dotsc, z_n)$ is a common zero of $f_1, \dotsc, f_r$ in $F_p$.

Comment: I just have a couple of follow-up questions: 1) if we take each coefficient of the $g_i$ to be a unique indeterminate, does't the identity $f_1g_1 + ... + f_rg_r = 1$ become a single linear equation, not a system? (Unless you meant a trivial 'system')  2) Why does the existence of the $g_i$ imply the existence of a solution (to the identity in the indeterminates) in $\mathbb{Q}$? 3) What is $d_{y_i}$ here and how does it relate to $d$? I don't understand the notation. 4) What do you mean by choose a prime ideal 'above' $p$? Thanks!

Comment: @User095746 Think of the identity $f_1g_1+\cdots+f_rg_r=1$ as an identity of polynomials in $n$ variables with the (finitely many) coefficients of the polynomials $g_i$ as unknowns. There are finitely many monomials appearing in that polynomial identity. Equating the coefficients of all those monomials gives you a linear system in the unknown coefficients of $g_i$s.

Comment: And, $dy_i$ is just the product $d\cdot y_i$. The discussion about prime ideals above $p$ is just basic algebraic number theory jargon. $\mathcal{P}$ is simply one of the maximal ideals of $\mathcal{O}_E$ with the property that $\mathcal{P}\cap\Bbb{Z}=p\Bbb{Z}$. Such ideals exist for all finite extension fields $E$ of $\Bbb{Q}$ and all prime numbers $p$.

Comment: 1) it's an identity of polynomials, so considered as linear equations over $\mathbb C$, there is one equation for every monomial, although on the right hand side only the constant term is non-zero. 2) it's an exercise in linear algebra: if $K/L$ is any field extension, then a system of linear equations with coefficients in $L$ has a solution over $K$ iff it has a solution over $L$. ...After typing these (on my smartphone), I see that @JyrkiLahtonen answered 3) and 4).

Comment: I see. Thank you both very much!